# Getting Doctrine for a Symfony console command

Tags: symfony

How do I get an instance of doctrine into a symfony console command app?
I need to run some tasks via a cron job and need to access the database and send emails too.

Comment: Could you add some more information to your question? Like: What did you try? Which doc articles did you read in order to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command must extends `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand`class.

Then :

```
$em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
```

Comment: I wasn't running the command via app/console, I was trying to do it via a separate PHP script.